# What is the fastest way to find the first record in Rails (ActiveRecord)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I would like to know which method is fastest for return a record.

```
Class.where(:type => 4).first
Class.find(:first, :conditions => ["type = ?", 4])
```

Is the execution exactly the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both would produce the same query.

[According to the latest information, under Rails 3.1, passing in :conditions will be deprecated.](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface)

Hence, right now, the best way to execute the query is to use:

```
Class.where(:type => 4).first
```

Answer (score 17):

The most performant, assuming you don't care about the order, is to use `find_by`:

```rb
Class.find_by(type: 4)
```

From https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rails-style-guide/issues/76

> This method has been added on Rails 4 and it is defined like this:
>
> ```rb
> def find_by(*args)
>  where(*args).take
> end
> ```
>
> So, `take` differs from `first` in regards to the order of your records. `first` will return the first record according to the order of the primary key while `take` will just return whatever the database spits out first.
>
> So while using `where().take` is equivalent to `find_by` and choosing whether to use one of the other is a matter of taste, `where().first` differs from `find_by` in a subtle and not so obvious way.